# Can we use JSX in a NodeJS backend to build XML?

Tags: node.js, xml, typescript, jsx

In the frontend, React uses JSX to render the HTML of its components.

Is JSX (or similar) functionality available in a NodeJS backend, specifically to render (conditional) XML?

Currently we use template literals to build our XML, but in comparison to JSX our team agrees that this is a suboptimal way of building markup. Hence we are looking for a different solution.

Comment: JSX is a syntax extension for **JavaScript** and produces React elements, so I would say no. You are right that template literals are probably not the way to go either. We often use some kind of [xml builders](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder)  to make generating XML  easier. Even if you were able to use JSX for this, I'd take a guess that it would have tons of overhead for no reason. Better to choose the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and we have looked into such XML builder as well. However, we do not think this is the right way of handling XML in JavaScript. Because in the end, XML is a markup language itself, and using an abstraction layer on top of XML creates  complexity that we'd rather avoid.

Comment: There's this https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-xml

Comment: @Swiffy Make that an answer

Comment: If you're open to a solution using XSLT, consider the SaxonJS library.

Answer (score 0):

JSX is a syntax extension for **JavaScript** and produces React elements, so I would say no. You are right that template literals are probably not the way to go either. We often use some kind of xml builders to make generating XML easier. Even if you were able to use JSX for this, I'd take a guess that it would have tons of overhead for no reason. Better to choose the right tool for the job.

If you really want to try to do it with JSX though, there's this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsx-xml

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and we have looked into such XML builder as well. 

However, we do not think this is the right way of handling XML in JavaScript. Because in the end, XML is a markup language itself, and using an abstraction layer on top of XML creates complexity that we'd rather avoid.

The package you mentioned looks like what we're after, though it does not seem to be actively maintained. I'll look into it, thanks.